# android obfuscation in proguard

Tags: android, obfuscation

I have used 3 libraries as below in my gradle

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile files('libs/okhttp-2.3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/okio-1.3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/retrofit-1.9.0.jar')
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.0.2'
compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
```

everything is fine without obfuscation but when I turn minifyEnabled true below error is happening and code doesnt compile at all

```
Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:client:generateDebugSources,              :client:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :core:generateDebugSources,   :core:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :driver:generateDebugSources, :driver:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
Information:12/3/2015 10:47 AM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0     warnings in 6s 771ms
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':core:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

warnings are like these

```
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.sink
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 17215: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newOutputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/OutputStream;
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
```

i tested all of these but not is working

```
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn java.io.**
-dontwarn Ljava.io.**
-dontwarn Ljava.nio.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-dontwarn android.content.**
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.json.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class okio.** { *; }
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.* { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.* { *; }
-keep class retrofit.* { *; }
-dontwarn rx.*
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.** { *; }
```

I have these warning in debug mode

```
unable to resolve virtual method 631: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
unable to resolve virtual method 633: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
unable to resolve virtual method 668:  Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
unable to resolve virtual method 690: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I

W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.sink
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 17215:   Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newOutputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;  [Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/OutputStream;
D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature  (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.source
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 17214:    Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newInputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path; [Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/InputStream;
D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
```

is anyone knows where the problem is?

Comment: What are the Warnings throwed ?

Comment: i dont have any, but in debug mode are as above as i sent

Comment: Look at the Messages tab

Comment: they are in the question

Comment: you should add this -keep class Ljava.nio.** { *; } in your proguard

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }

-keep class com.parse.** { *; }

-keep class com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient** { *; }

-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }

-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }

-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }

-dontwarn com.daimajia.androidanimations.**

-dontwarn android.support.design.**

-dontwarn com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient**

-dontwarn com.parse.**

-dontwarn org.apache.lang.**

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-dontwarn com.squareup.**

-keepattributes *Annotation*,SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keepattributes Signature

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
```